# Priority of the unary operations

Tags: java

Here is an example that outputs `6`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 1;
    m(++i);
}

static void m(int i) {
    i = ++i + i++; 
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

We get `6` because in the `m(int i)` method at first `3` and `3` are summarized, then `i` becomes `4` (due to the `i++`), but after that `i` from the left part takes the summarized `6` value.

But if the method is changed to the following, we get `7`:

```
static void m(int i) {
    i = ++i + ++i; 
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

But I expected to see `7` in both cases (I've been guided by the fact that unary operations, in this case incrementing, have a higher priority than binary operations). Could someone please provide an explanation (or a reference to an explanation) of the ignored `i++` in the first example?

Comment: The increment operators run from left to right, and the `i++` one returns the result before incrementing, i. e. ++i makes i 6, then i+i gets calculated, then i++ increments another time.

Comment: `i++ + ++i` would show you 2+4=6 too and `i++ + i++` is 2+3 = 5

Comment: last but not least `i = i++` has no effect since it will assign the value before incrementing back to i :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`++i` increments `i` and returns the **new** value of `i`.

`i++` increments `i` and returns the **old** value of `i`.

Expressions are evaluated from left to right, taking operator precedence into account.

So in `++i + i++`, when you start with `i == 2`, you get: `++i` which increments `i` to `3` and returns `3`; then `i++` which increments `i` to `4` and returns `3`. Then finally you have `i = 3 + 3` so `i` becomes `6`.

Note that these are funny tricks that are not really relevant to real-world programming.

Comment: Thanks, the absence of such cases in the real-world programming is promising.

Comment: I don't fully agree with your last paragraph. Weirdnesses like `++i + i++` aren't relevant to real-world programming, but the OP seems to have been unaware of the difference between `++i` and `i++`, and *that* difference *is* relevant to real-world programming.

Comment: @ruakh Indeed, the difference between `++i` and `i++` is certainly important. What I meant was that you should never write tricky, hard to understand statements like `i = ++i + i++` in real software.

Comment: @ruakh Well, you're right, but the question was not really about the difference between `++i` and `i++` (as you can see, I described the process of what's going on in the first code sample in the question). I wanted to have a clear understanding of the relationship between `=` and `i++` in the first described case.

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone please provide an explanation (or a reference to an explanation) of the ignored `i++` in the first example?

`i++` is a postincrement; it increments `i`, but evaluates to the value of `i` from before the increment. So, for example:

```
int i = 3;
System.out.println(i++); // prints 3
// now, i == 4
```

In other words, you can think of `i++` as meaning `((i += 1) - 1)`. So, in your example:

```
i = ++i + i++;
```

the `i++` at the end isn't exactly *ignored* — it does increment `i` — but it immediately gets superseded by the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The incrementation isn't ignored; it's a *postincrement* operator (i.e. it applies *after* `i` has been referenced).  Let's walk through the code.

When you add `(++i + i++)`, it's being done from left to right.  This is to say, whatever value i has is first preincremented (so it would take 2 to 3), then add 2.  `i` has finished its reference, so it would add another 1, for a total of 6.

In your second example, when you add `(++i + ++i)`, the value of `i` is preincremented twice, so you would see `3 + 4`.

Comment: I edited your answer to change "postfix" to "postincrement", which I think is what you meant; but then I undid my edit, because it's really up to you. But I think you want "postincrement". ("Postfix" just has to do with its physical position, not with when it is applied.)

Comment: I'm fine with it; I'm glad you caught that.  That's exactly what I meant.  Thanks!